# undefined function when calling javascript prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype

i have the following javascript object:

```
var Playlist = function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/playlist'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        this.html = data;
        callback({},this);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        callback(err,{});
    });
};
```

for this object, i declared a prototype method:

```
Playlist.prototype = {
    render : function() {
        $('#main').html(this.html);
    }
};
```

now, when i create a new object und try to call the 'render' function like this

```
function renderPlaylist() {
    var playlist = new Playlist(function(err, obj) {
        obj.render();
    });
}

renderPlaylist();
```

i get a 'undefined is not a function'. it seems not to know the render function, which i declared in the prototype. what am i missing here? thanks for help.

Comment: `callback({},this);` the `this` is not what you think. See [JavaScript “this” keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword), [MDN `this` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: thank you, you are totally right. i changed my constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of [Volune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191722/volune), i changed my constructor to

```
var Playlist = function(callback) {
    var playlist = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:'/mpdplaylist'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        playlist.html = data;
        callback(null,playlist);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        callback(err,{});
    });
};
```

now it works. thank you!!

**edit:** 
as Volune pointed out, i replaced the empty object for the error with null in the 'done' callback function

Comment: If you're using callbacks the same way as NodeJS, you should do `callback(null,playlist);`. This way the callback can more easily check if there were an error.